# Android Studio - Device File Explorer Picture Directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have succefully created an Inten to take a photo and save it in this directory:

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.iyfuture.peddypaper/files/Pictures/Image.jpg**

After this I do a display of this picture (using the previous URI directory) to make sure that is working. And it is!
My question now is related with the android studio device file explorer.

If I wasn´t sucessfull to do the display of this image how could I check if it is inside this directory. 
**In other words how can I find this image inside the device file explorer?**

I have searched in the "popular" directory data/data/com.iyfuture.peddypaper but there is nothing there...
I also have the device file explorer **synchronized** and the mobile phone **emulator** I am using it is the same as the one that is selected on top of the device file explorer.

Comment: What is the device file explorer? Name? How do you start it? Every file manager app can browse that path.

Comment: Device file explorer is an interface in Android Studio that allows you to see directories and files created inside the mobile phone emulator.
Here's a link with more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/device-file-explorer?hl=pt-br 
Thank you for pointing that up.

Comment: And why cant you find your files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is under `sdcard/Android/data/com.iyfuture.peddypaper/files/Pictures/Image.jpg`